# Unable to fetch from URL

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript . I was going through this tutorial [async/await with Generators](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-generators-in-javascript)

I am typing this code in console but I am getting this error .

```
const getUsers = async function() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const json = await response.json()

  return json
}

// Call the getUsers function and log the response
getUsers().then(response => console.log(response))
```

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem so that I can fetch the JSON data and continue
my execution

Thank you

Comment: Your code runs just fine if you open dev tools and paste it in...

Comment: Please append a catch() block at the end and log the full error message. `getUsers().then(response => console.log(response)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsbin.com/wedovozune/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @rezso.dev I got this as output "VM41:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: please also check before .json() with console.log(response.ok, response.statusText). its hard to debug without reproducing the issue

Comment: I am not able to understand you rezso

Comment: add “console.log(response.ok, response.statusText)” after the line “const response = ...” and paste the output please

Comment: Rezso here is the output . [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lq0ye5GybQLBmIDUtSTzKqTD-GWbiRiW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: is the url `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` accessible from your browser?

Comment: There is some problem with chrome browser . With firefox I am able to fetch from URL .